# Unable to receive SNS Email notification Aamazon Web Services AWS

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, iot, esp32

I am new to AWS and using [this GitHub example](https://github.com/mongoose-os-apps/aws-iot-button) to get email notification. Working on a Mac system, I have followed all the steps mentioned in the example and have everything setup as instructed.

After rebooting the ESP, my log looks like this

```
[Nov  4 10:44:18.460] ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

[Nov  4 10:44:18.460] 

[Nov  4 10:44:18.460] rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)

[Nov  4 10:44:18.881] ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

[Nov  4 10:44:18.881] 

[Nov  4 10:44:18.881] rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)

[Nov  4 10:44:18.881] configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee

[Nov  4 10:44:18.881] clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00

[Nov  4 10:44:18.881] mode:DIO, clock div:2

[Nov  4 10:44:18.881] load:0x3fff0010,len:4

[Nov  4 10:44:18.881] load:0x3fff0014,len:5244

[Nov  4 10:44:18.881] load:0x40078000,len:0

[Nov  4 10:44:18.881] load:0x40078000,len:13400

[Nov  4 10:44:18.881] entry 0x40078b38

[Nov  4 10:44:18.928] [0;32mI (28) boot: ESP-IDF v1.0-2569-gc60279b 2nd stage bootloader[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.928] [0;32mI (28) boot: compile time 11:02:31[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.928] [0;32mI (28) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source...[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.928] [0;32mI (34) boot: SPI Speed      : 40MHz[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.928] [0;32mI (38) boot: SPI Mode       : DIO[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.928] [0;32mI (42) boot: SPI Flash Size : 4MB[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.928] [0;32mI (46) boot: Partition Table:[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.928] [0;32mI (50) boot: ## Label            Usage          Type ST Offset   Length   Flags[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.928] [0;32mI (58) boot:  0 nvs              WiFi data        01 02 00009000 00004000 00000000[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.975] [0;32mI (66) boot:  1 otadata          OTA data         01 00 0000d000 00002000 00000000[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.975] [0;32mI (74) boot:  2 app_0            OTA app          00 10 00010000 00180000 00000000[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.975] [0;32mI (82) boot:  3 fs_0             SPIFFS           01 82 00190000 00040000 00000000[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.975] [0;32mI (91) boot:  4 app_1            OTA app          00 11 001d0000 00180000 00000000[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:18.975] [0;32mI (99) boot:  5 fs_1             SPIFFS           01 82 00350000 00040000 00000000[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.006] [0;32mI (107) boot: End of partition table[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.006] [0;32mI (111) boot: OTA data 0: seq 0x00000001, st 0x10, CRC 0x157a2b85, valid? 1[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.006] [0;32mI (119) boot: OTA data 1: seq 0x00000000, st 0x00, CRC 0x00000000, valid? 0[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.006] [0;32mI (127) boot: Disabling RNG early entropy source...[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.006] [0;32mI (132) esp_image: segment 0: paddr=0x00010020 vaddr=0x3f400020 size=0x4a334 (303924) map[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.146] [0;32mI (247) esp_image: segment 1: paddr=0x0005a35c vaddr=0x3ffc0000 size=0x02ce0 ( 11488) load[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.146] [0;32mI (252) esp_image: segment 2: paddr=0x0005d044 vaddr=0x40080000 size=0x00400 (  1024) load[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.146] [0;32mI (255) esp_image: segment 3: paddr=0x0005d44c vaddr=0x40080400 size=0x02bc4 ( 11204) load[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.146] [0;32mI (268) esp_image: segment 4: paddr=0x00060018 vaddr=0x400d0018 size=0xf0640 (984640) map[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.474] [0;32mI (615) esp_image: segment 5: paddr=0x00150660 vaddr=0x40082fc4 size=0x11638 ( 71224) load[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.505] [0;32mI (644) esp_image: segment 6: paddr=0x00161ca0 vaddr=0x400c0000 size=0x00034 (    52) load[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.552] [0;32mI (657) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.552] [0;32mI (657) cpu_start: Single core mode[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.552] [0;32mI (657) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.552] [0;32mI (661) heap_init: At 3FFAFF10 len 000000F0 (0 KiB): DRAM[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.552] [0;32mI (667) heap_init: At 3FFD8078 len 00007F88 (31 KiB): DRAM[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.552] [0;32mI (673) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003BC0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.552] [0;32mI (679) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.552] [0;32mI (686) heap_init: At 400945FC len 0000BA04 (46 KiB): IRAM[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.567] [0;32mI (692) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.567] [0;32mI (38) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.583] m     }  }          0x3ffdf224 Mongoose init

[Nov  4 10:44:19.583] esp32_mgos_init      default 1.0 (20171101-110218/1.19.5@92a0b527)
[Nov  4 10:44:19.599] esp32_mgos_init      Mongoose OS 2017110111 (20171101-110235/???)
[Nov  4 10:44:19.599] esp32_mgos_init      ESP-IDF v1.0-2569-gc60279b
[Nov  4 10:44:19.599] esp32_mgos_init      Boot partition: app_0; flash: 4M; RAM: 161512 total, 123396 free
[Nov  4 10:44:19.614] mgos_vfs_dev_open    esp32part ({"label": "fs_0", "subtype": 130}) -> 0x3ffdf6b0
[Nov  4 10:44:19.630] mgos_vfs_mount       Mount SPIFFS @ / (dev 0x3ffdf6b0, opts {"encr": false}) -> 0x3ffdf6c0
[Nov  4 10:44:19.708] mgos_vfs_mount       /: size 233681, used: 102659, free: 131022
[Nov  4 10:44:19.786] mgos_sys_config_init MAC: 30AEA40550A8
[Nov  4 10:44:19.786] mgos_sys_config_init WDT: 30 seconds
[Nov  4 10:44:19.786] mgos_mdns_init       Listening on udp://:5353
[Nov  4 10:44:19.801] mgos_mdns_hal_join_g Joining multicast group 224.0.0.251
[Nov  4 10:44:19.801] mgos_mdns_hal_join_g udp_join_multigrup failed!
[Nov  4 10:44:19.817] mgos_i2c_create      I2C GPIO init ok (SDA: 32, SCL: 33)
[Nov  4 10:44:19.817] mgos_aws_init        AWS Greengrass enable (0)
[Nov  4 10:44:19.833] mgos_bt_common_init  Bluetooth is disabled
[Nov  4 10:44:19.833] mgos_wifi_set_config WiFi mode: STA
[Nov  4 10:44:19.833] esp32_wifi_set_mode  WiFi mode: STA
[Nov  4 10:44:19.848] E (581) wifi: esp_wifi_set_mode 779 wifi is not init
[Nov  4 10:44:19.864] I (581) wifi: wifi firmware version: 7bd4899
[Nov  4 10:44:19.864] I (591) wifi: config NVS flash: enabled
[Nov  4 10:44:19.864] I (591) wifi: config nano formating: disabled
[Nov  4 10:44:19.864] [0;32mI (601) system_api: Base MAC address is not set, read default base MAC address from BLK0 of EFUSE[0m
[Nov  4 10:44:19.879] [0;32mI (611) system_api: Base MAC address is not set, read default base MAC address from BLK0 of EFUSE[0m
[Nov  4 10:44:19.895] I (621) wifi: Init dynamic tx buffer num: 32
[Nov  4 10:44:19.895] I (631) wifi: Init data frame dynamic rx buffer num: 64
[Nov  4 10:44:19.895] I (631) wifi: Init management frame dynamic rx buffer num: 64
[Nov  4 10:44:19.911] I (641) wifi: wifi driver task: 3ffe3d34, prio:23, stack:4096
[Nov  4 10:44:19.911] I (651) wifi: Init static rx buffer num: 10
[Nov  4 10:44:19.911] I (651) wifi: Init dynamic rx buffer num: 0
[Nov  4 10:44:19.926] I (661) wifi: Init rx ampdu len mblock:7
[Nov  4 10:44:19.926] I (661) wifi: Init lldesc rx ampdu entry mblock:4
[Nov  4 10:44:19.942] I (671) wifi: wifi power manager task: 0x3ffe9528 prio: 21 stack: 2560
[Nov  4 10:44:19.942] I (681) wpa: WPA2 ENTERPRISE VERSION: [v2.0] disable
[Nov  4 10:44:19.942] 
[Nov  4 10:44:19.957] mgos_wifi_setup_sta  WiFi STA: Connecting to PE-2
[Nov  4 10:44:19.957] E (691) wifi: esp_wifi_connect 836 wifi not start
[Nov  4 10:44:19.989] [0;32mI (721) phy: phy_version: 362.0, 61e8d92, Sep  8 2017, 18:48:11, 0, 0[0m

[Nov  4 10:44:19.989] I (721) wifi: mode : sta (30:ae:a4:05:50:a8)
[Nov  4 10:44:20.004] mgos_http_server_ini HTTP server started on [80]
[Nov  4 10:44:20.004] mg_rpc_channel_mqtt  0x3ffea64c esp32_0550A8/rpc/#
[Nov  4 10:44:20.020] mg_rpc_channel_uart  0x3ffea9c8 UART0
[Nov  4 10:44:20.020] mgos_init            Init done, RAM: 160748 total, 87480 free, 87480 min free
[Nov  4 10:44:20.145] Flash button is configured on GPIO pin  0 
[Nov  4 10:44:20.145] Press the flash button now! 
[Nov  4 10:44:20.145] mongoose_poll        New heap free LWM: 76444
[Nov  4 10:44:20.160] mgos_net_on_change_c WiFi STA: connecting
[Nov  4 10:44:21.330] I (2061) wifi: n:11 0, o:1 0, ap:255 255, sta:11 0, prof:1
[Nov  4 10:44:22.173] I (2901) wifi: state: init -> auth (b0)
[Nov  4 10:44:22.173] I (2911) wifi: state: auth -> assoc (0)
[Nov  4 10:44:22.188] I (2921) wifi: state: assoc -> run (10)
[Nov  4 10:44:22.204] I (2941) wifi: connected with PE-2, channel 11
[Nov  4 10:44:22.219] mgos_net_on_change_c WiFi STA: connected
[Nov  4 10:44:22.391] [0;32mI (3131) event: sta ip: 192.168.3.24, mask: 255.255.255.0, gw: 192.168.3.1[0m
[Nov  4 10:44:22.407] mgos_net_on_change_c WiFi STA: ready, IP 192.168.3.24, GW 192.168.3.1, DNS 8.8.8.8
[Nov  4 10:44:22.422] mgos_mqtt_global_con MQTT connecting to a2wstxxxxxxxxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:8883
[Nov  4 10:44:22.453] mongoose_poll        New heap free LWM: 75124
[Nov  4 10:44:22.453] mongoose_poll        New heap free LWM: 74280
[Nov  4 10:44:23.124] SW ECDSA verify curve 3 hash_len 32 sig_len 72
[Nov  4 10:44:23.982] SW ECDSA verify curve 3 hash_len 64 sig_len 71
[Nov  4 10:44:24.809] SW ECDH curve 3
[Nov  4 10:44:25.199] I (5931) wifi: pm start, type:0
[Nov  4 10:44:25.199] 
[Nov  4 10:44:26.073] mongoose_poll        New heap free LWM: 61344
[Nov  4 10:44:26.073] mgos_sntp_query      SNTP query to pool.ntp.org
[Nov  4 10:44:26.151] mgos_sntp_ev         SNTP reply from 123.108.200.124: time 1509772461.460180, local 6.578079, delta 1509772454.882101
[Nov  4 10:44:26.603] mgos_mqtt_ev         MQTT TCP connect ok (0)
[Nov  4 10:44:26.931] mgos_mqtt_ev         MQTT CONNACK 0
[Nov  4 10:44:26.931] do_subscribe         Subscribing to 'esp32_0550A8/rpc'
[Nov  4 10:44:26.946] do_subscribe         Subscribing to 'esp32_0550A8/rpc/#'
```

And when I click the Boot button on my esp32, I get the following log

```
[Nov  4 10:44:40.083] Published: yes topic: esp32_0550A8/button_pressed message: {"free_ram":80904,"total_ram":160340}
```

Please note:
I have received the first, "AWS Notification - Subscription Confirmation" email. I clicked on the "Confirm Subscription" on which, my browser windows showed "You have subscribed xxxxx@gmail.com to the topic xyz".

The problem is, I receive no other notification after pressing the Boot button on the ESP apart from the message on my MOS UI "Published: yes topic: esp32_0550A8/button_pressed message: {"free_ram":80904,"total_ram":160340}"

Comment: You need to break the problem down to something you can solve ,  is the message getting to topic?, is the lambda function being triggered?  Is the lambda function generating errors? Is the email being filtered?

Comment: When I push Reset button on ESP, I can see the Topic activity as, Thing connected, thing disconnected, thing subscribed and one more time thing subscribed. But when I push boot button on ESP, nothing happens apart from the log message I just posted. https://imgur.com/a/4Fzac Is what I see in Lambda function. Sorry, I am really new to this whole AWS and mongoose environment so still figuring out the debugging.